# Getting memory error while dropping the duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to drop duplicates based on two columns but it is giving me MemoryError or It is killing the process after some time. Can you please help how to resolve this issue?

Example:

First I am concatenating 3 data frames into one and then dropping the duplicates but it is giving me error. Can you please what I am doing wrong here.

```
df_final = pd.concat([df3, df2, df1_new], axis=1)
df_final1 = df_final.drop_duplicates(subset=['SOURCE_ID', 'SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE'], keep=False, inplace=True)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "incre_logic.py", line 33, in <module>
    df_final.groupby(['SOURCE_ID', 'SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE']).filter(lambda df_final:df_final.shape[0] == 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 7632, in groupby
    observed=observed, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 2110, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 335, in __init__
    obj._consolidate_inplace()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5138, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._protect_consolidate(f)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5127, in _protect_consolidate
    result = f()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5136, in f
    self._data = self._data.consolidate()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 924, in consolidate
    bm._consolidate_inplace()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 929, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1899, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 3146, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = np.vstack([b.values for b in blocks])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 283, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
MemoryError
```

Comment: How big are your DataFrames? It seems like you're running out of memory.

Comment: Can you also share the top few values of your dataframes?

Comment: It appears that you are using python 2. Is there a special reason ? Can you also show the output of `pandas.__version__` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.
Note: the method `concat` should be used with the option `axis=0` to keep 2 rows.
For `drop_duplicates`, either use `inplace=True` without using assignment to another df, either use `df_final1 = ...` without the option `inplace`.

```py
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0)
df_final.drop_duplicates(subset=['SOURCE_ID', 'SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE'], keep=False, inplace=True)
```